# Editors can't access the website when it's offline

Tags: ee, offline

I have a member group called "Editors" and I gave permission to the editors to be able to view the website when it's offline. They could access the control panel but they couldn't access the website unfortunately.

Sometimes I face the same problem as an Admin when I try to login to my account using windows computers. I tried to use different browsers but the problem would always occur.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevDemon's [Smart Switch](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/smart_switch) might help you with that.